# Binary serialization of datasets parameters in web services

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, asmx

In a system with both ends (client and server) in .NET, is it possible to use the binary serialization provided by the dataset class in ADO.NET 2.0 when the datasets are exposed as WebMethods parameters ?

Is it ok to use something like the following just before the dataset is returned:

someDataSet.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;

Answer (score 0):

WCF supports TCP/IP, Named Pipes and MSMQ transports using a binary serialization format (not the old "binary serialization").

ASMX web services only support SOAP over HTTP, hosted by IIS. They are also considered by Microsoft to be a "legacy technology". Any new development should use WCF.

Finally, you shouldn't be transferring a DataSet. It's very and it's platform-specific. There have even been problems between different .NET versions in transferring a DataSet.